# tmux set window title

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux, terminal-emulator

when I use my shell, it sets automatically the title of the terminal (emulator) window dynamically. When I now use tmux, this window title set by the shell (bash in my case) is displayed on the right side of the statusline (by default) and for the terminal (emulator) window tmux offers some functionality to set this title as well (`set-titles on`).

Now I need to pass the title set by the shell on to the terminal(emulator) window again (displaying the shell-set title of the currently in tmux active pane.

How is this possible? (if it helps, I always have `-${HOSTNAME} - ${PWD}` setting the title to hostname - current directory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `pane_title` format. For example, set `set-titles-string` with:

```
set -g set-titles-string '#{pane_title}'
```

Comment: Looks like tmux includes `pane_title` in the `set-titles-string` by default, now. `set -g set-titles on` is now sufficient to pass through the child title to the terminal emulator.